# configured logging driver does not support reading : Docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, aws-batch

I am running my docker container in AWS ECS. When i try to execute the below command to read the logs from container, i am facing the below error.

command:  docker logs -f "Container ID"

Error response from daemon: configured logging driver does not support reading.

Any feasible solutions are welcome.

Comment: can you share the output of "docker info" and "docker inspect <container> ?

Comment: Is your container/daemon/agent [configured to use the awslogs log driver](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_awslogs.html)?

Comment: Did u specify your docker log driver? I think that’s the issue. You may share your Docker configuration above in your question.

Comment: Hello, This container is managed by AWS Batch. Where i can see the logs in AWS Cloudwatch. But If I log into container instance and execute "docker logs -f "Container ID"" , then I am facing above mentioned error.

Answer (score 10):

According to information commented by David Maze, you must have your container run with a awslogs log driver.

Here is the [setting introduction.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_storage)

After changing log driver to `json-file,` you could get log by executing `docker logs container-id/name`.

But still note this:

> If using the Fargate launch type, the only supported value is awslogs.

Answer (score 6):

You are using `awslogs` log-driver, and `docker logs` command is not available for that driver.

From the docs:

> The docker logs command is not available for drivers other than
>   json-file and journald

[limitations of logging drivers](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/#limitations-of-logging-drivers)

Answer (score 3):

I got this issue because docker is out of storage.
I fixed it by removing old docker images with `docker rmi <immage_id_1> <immage_id_2>`

Answer (score 1):

I have had this same issue before.

In my specific case the Task Definition for that service in ECS had the Log Configuration's logDriver  set to `fluentd` see the circled image below.

[image]

To resolve the issue, I created another Task Definition with all the same parameters except I left the `Log Configuration` section's Log Driver to **default**.  note if you click on that you'll see other log drivers including **fluentd**.

After that I pointed the service to this task definition in my ECS cluster, and now I can see the logs doing the commands `docker logs <container id>`

[image]